# pickle load No module named '__builtin__'

Tags: python-3.x, load, pickle, built-in

Can someone help me here. I haven't found a solution online that work yet

```
print('Restoring variable environment')
with open(VARIABLES_FILE,'rb') as variables_file:
    Compartment_CL = pickle.load(variables_file)
    MetList_CL = pickle.load(variables_file)
    GeneList = pickle.load(variables_file)
    RxnList_CL = pickle.load(variables_file)
print('Variable environment restored')
```

````
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [103], line 6
      4     MetList_CL = pickle.load(variables_file)
      5     GeneList = pickle.load(variables_file)
----> 6     RxnList_CL = pickle.load(variables_file)
      7 print('Variable environment restored')```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__builtin__'
````

Comment: When I saw such problem, now I create a fresh new environment. Upgrades (conda, pip) may leave some old files, which confuses python interpreter, so it mixes versions). It may not be your case, but my experience (on my usage of environments) it is often the case.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how I can solve it. Thanks Giacomo!